# Hash "has_key" complexity in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, hash, time-complexity

I have a hash `vars = {"a" => "Name", "b" => "Address" , "c" => "Phone"}`. I want to check the performance of this line :

```
vars.has_key(:b)?
```

Is it O(1) or O(size of hash) ?

Comment: The hash is direct-access, not like a stack (array), which you need to go through every element untill you find the one you want. Therefore, `has_key` should not depend on the hash's size (to be confirmed but I'm pretty sure of it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

iterations = 10_000
small      = 10
big        = 1_000_000

small_hash = {}
big_hash   = {}

(1..small).each do |i|
  small_hash[i] = i
end

(1..big).each do |i|
  big_hash[i] = i
end

Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('Small Hash') do
    iterations.times { small_hash.has_key?(1) }
  end

  bm.report('Big Hash') do
    iterations.times { big_hash.has_key?(1) }
  end
end
```

Running the test:

```
$ ruby has_key_test.rb 
                 user     system      total        real
Small Hash   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001167)
Big Hash     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001171)
```

So yes, I think we can consider the cost constant O(1) (at least, without check the internal MRI implementation).

**NOTE** This is not 100% true in all scenarios, see more details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30193740/3033649).

Comment: To perform a good benchmark, you need to perform more than one iteration of the method you are invoking. In fact I recommend that you do at least 10^5 iterations to have a good approximation.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev yep, you're right, that was just a quick approximation. I'll update it using `Benchmark.bmbm` and more iterations.

Comment: @markets - How about `has_value?`? I tried your code with modifying `has_key?(1)` to `has_value?(big - 1)`, then the big hash will cost (big / small) x time. So I think the time complexity for `has_value?` is O(n)?

Comment: This is only proving for the best case. Ruby (and several languages) use packed arrays to improve performance, and your example is using a packed structure. That means that has_key? is going to use a specific algorithm which is O(1).

That not always the case, try adding random elements and strings to the Hash, and you're going to get an O(n) complexity

Answer (score 5):

The source code of `has_key` is (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F)

```
rb_hash_has_key(VALUE hash, VALUE key)
{
    if (!RHASH(hash)->ntbl)
        return Qfalse;
    if (st_lookup(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, 0)) {
        return Qtrue;
    }
    return Qfalse;
}
```

The `st_lookup` has following fragment (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca6b174078fa15f33655be704d9409fdbc4f9929/st.c#L383):

```
if (table->entries_packed) {
    st_index_t i = find_packed_index(table, hash_val, key);
    if (i < table->real_entries) {
        if (value != 0) *value = PVAL(table, i);
        return 1;
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Which tells us that if `entries_packed` then ruby uses index (O(1)) otherwise it uses unindexed search (O(n)).

Value of `entries_packed` seems to depend on the size of hash: (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca6b174078fa15f33655be704d9409fdbc4f9929/st.c#L41)

```
#define MAX_PACKED_HASH (int)(ST_DEFAULT_PACKED_TABLE_SIZE * sizeof(st_table_entry*) / sizeof(st_packed_entry))
```

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca6b174078fa15f33655be704d9409fdbc4f9929/st.c#L219

```
tbl->entries_packed = size <= MAX_PACKED_HASH;
```

The `size` is a kind of size of index.

You can find out more details in ruby sources but its complexity is not always O(1) but depends on the size of the hash. (on the size of its index)

Answer (score 2):

The **expected** complexity of the method is constant.

Comment: How is the reader able to assess the validity of your assertion? If you're not Matz (or one of a few others), you need to give a reference or provide a proof.

Answer (score -1):

```
def fake_h(n)
  n.times.inject({}){|o,x| o[x] = :a; o}
end

n = 1000000;
h1 = fake_h(1);
h10 = fake_h(10);
h100 = fake_h(100);
h1000 = fake_h(1000);
h10000 = fake_h(10000);
h100000 = fake_h(100000);
h1000000 = fake_h(1000000);

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report { n.times{|t| h1.has_key?(t) } }
  x.report { n.times{|t| h10.has_key?(t) } }
  x.report { n.times{|t| h100.has_key?(t) } }
  x.report { n.times{|t| h1000.has_key?(t) } }
  x.report { n.times{|t| h10000.has_key?(t) } }
  x.report { n.times{|t| h100000.has_key?(t) } }
  x.report { n.times{|t| h1000000.has_key?(t) } }
end

# Result :
    user     system      total         real
0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.204647)
0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.205677)
0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.214393)
0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.206382)
0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.208998)
0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.206821)
0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.213316)
```

The difference between an hash with 1 entry or 1 million entries is... minimal.

Comment: and what if key is not Symbol but String?

Comment: my keys are not symbols but integers. Just replace `o[x] = :a` by `o[x.to_s] = :a` and `h.has_key?(t)` by `h.has_key?(t.to_s)` and execute the code...

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm why didn't you use an array? You would have saved a lot of extra lines ...

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I can do that... I have written this benchmark in 2 minutes, with a lot of copy paste.